# WPF: Scale Grid without scaling content

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to apply a scale transform a Grid's columns and rows without scaling the content?

I would like the content of each cell to simply resize to fit the cell without being scaled (e.g. font size of text remains the same).

For example, in the following piece of XAML I would like the buttons to resize rather than scale:

```
<Grid Name="grid1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider1 }" ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider1 }"
                                />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Button Content="Button3" Margin="6" Name="button3" />
            <Button Content="Button4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6" Name="button4" />
            <Button Content="Button5" Grid.Column="2" Margin="6" Name="button5" />
            <Button Content="Button6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6" Name="button6" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the method you're applying, this isn't possible because the transform will apply to the rendering of all child controls, too.

However, by the look of your code, you want to resize your grid's columns based on the position of a slider.  An easier way would be to set all the columns to `Width="*"` (which will have the effect of each column having equal width), remove your transform, and bind the width of the grid as a whole to the slider instead (you may need to adjust the range of your slider to suit!).

This will have different effect to a RenderTransform, though, because a RenderTransform won't affect any of the surrounding layout, and changing the Width will.  Post a comment if that will be a problem and maybe there's another solution...

Comment: Thanks. That is a very good idea! The grid is itself inside a ScrollViewer that gives me a viewport on to different areas of the grid. Two problems remain, the Grid control is not square so I can't bind Width and Height directly to the slider. Also the scale functions as if the Transform Origin is set to top left and I'd rather it was the center of the grid (or better yet, the center of the viewport!). I guess I can't do it in xaml only so I should create a code object the calculates the rectangle and bind to this?

Comment: Regarding the non-square problem: instead of binding directly, you could use a converter on the binding to multiply your slider value by a fixed amount.  So, make your slider range 1.0 to 2.0, and bind to that with a converter that multiplies by whatever your original Width/Height are.  Still doesn't fix the centering problem, but it's a start :-)

Comment: I guess the centering problem is just a matter of applying converters to the top and left properties